# session() can't store new session key-value pair

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am not sure why it happens and I've been trying to debug it for an hour, I have the following code:

```
// some controller
public function some_method(Request $request)
{
    if(session()->missing('key1')) {
        session(['key1' => 'some_value1']);
        dd("key1 is missing");
    }

    if(session()->missing('key2')) {
        session(['key2' => 'some_value2']);
        dd("key2 is missing");
    }
}
```

After the first refresh, I get `"key1 is missing"` because it was not set at the first request. But then it keeps showing me `"key2 is missing"`. It enters the `if` condition but doesn't create the `key2` as it did with `key1`.

**Update:** If I set the `key2` outside the `if`, it works:

```
// some controller
public function some_method(Request $request)
{
    // setting key2 outside the if
    session(['key2' => 'some_value2']);

    if(session()->missing('key1')) {
        session(['key1' => 'some_value1']);
        dd("key1 is missing");
    }

    if(session()->missing('key2')) {
        session(['key2' => 'some_value2']);
        dd("key2 is missing");
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe don't use `dd()` which terminates the script? Have you tried `dump()` instead?

Answer (score -2):

In your original code, the issue is related to the order in which you're checking for the presence of the session keys and setting their values.

When you first access the page and the session is empty, the condition session()->missing('key1') evaluates to true because 'key1' is not yet set. Inside that condition, you set 'key1' to 'some_value1' using session(['key1' => 'some_value1']).

However, in the next condition, session()->missing('key2'), you expect 'key2' to be missing because you haven't set it yet. But the issue lies in the fact that the session() function starts a new session instance, and each call to session() returns a new session instance. So, when you call session(['key2' => 'some_value2']), it sets 'key2' on a different session instance, which doesn't affect the subsequent call to session()->missing('key2').

In your updated code, you set 'key2' outside of the if condition, ensuring that 'key2' is always set regardless of whether it was missing. That's why it works in this case.

To fix the original code while maintaining the same logic, you can use the put() method instead of the session() helper function to set the session values. The put() method sets the specified key-value pair in the current session instance. Here's the updated code:

```
public function some_method(Request $request)
{
if (session()->missing('key1')) {
    $request->session()->put('key1', 'some_value1');
    dd("key1 is missing");
}

if (session()->missing('key2')) {
    $request->session()->put('key2', 'some_value2');
    dd("key2 is missing");
}
}
```

By using $request->session()->put('key1', 'some_value1') and $request->session()->put('key2', 'some_value2'), you ensure that the keys are set on the same session instance, allowing you to check for their presence correctly.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT